# Alter array of arrays more elegantly

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array

This works but looks ugly as hell.

```
    # convert timestamps to psql timestamp format
    for block in ts_wrap_array:
        for date in block:
            ts_wrap_array[ts_wrap_array.index(block)][block.index(date)] = str(date).replace('.0', '000')
```

Anything I can apply to make this nicer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index, rather using `.index()` -

```
for block in ts_wrap_array:
    for j, date in enumerate(block):
       block[j] = str(date).replace('.0', '000')
```

---

A list comphrension alternative -

```
ts_wrap_array[:] = [[str(date).replace('.0', '000') for date in block] for block in ts_wrap_array]
```

Please note, this would not affect any other variables that are directly pointing to the inner lists (which would be affected when using the `for` loop method), Example -

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]]
>>> k = l[0]
>>> l[:] = [[x + 1 for x in y] for y in l]
>>> l
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
>>> k
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, if above case would be real for your case, you should use the `for` loop method given at the top of the answer.

Comment: Is this the best way?

Comment: Depends there is a list comprehension way, but that would not affect other names pointing to same list.

Comment: The first enumeration isn't necessary.

Comment: Correct, fixed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) the block:

```
for block in ts_wrap_array:
    for i, date in enumerate(block):
        block[i] = str(date).replace('.0', '000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for i, block in enumerate(ts_wrap_array):
        for j, date in enumerate(block):
            ts_wrap_array[i][j] = str(date).replace('.0', '000')
```